# How to read/write EMV Cards

Tags: emv

I want to read/write some test credit cards for testing with pos payment processing. Can you please guide me how i can create my own test visa/master/amex and discover credit cards.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Because of your question you have no necessary skills to make test cards yourself.
The complete learning course and best practices out of scope at this resource.

The solution is to purchase the test tools from different vendors like ICC Solution, UL, etc...

Or you may use test cards simulation tools with common profiles.

For example using your android mobile phone with NFC:

- Visa CDET only (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visa.app.cdet)
- HCEbridge - test sets with international card brands (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.iso8583.hcebridge)

Or, in case Magnetic swipe is enough for your testing, the writer for Magnetic Track 1 / Track 2 as well the blank plastic cards you may find at shops like Amazon.